# using dropdown list to select entries based on two tables

Tags: php

I wonder if someone can help with this. I'm a php/mysql newbie and would appreciate some assistance with dropdown lists.

I have two tables. One called simply "type" which contains a list of animal species type with 2 columns, a unique ID "IntTypeID" and a species type name, birds (ID=1), butterflies (ID=2), dragonflies (ID=3) etc. The other table called "species" is made up of 4 columns, a unique ID (IntSpeciesID), species latin name (StrLatinName), species English name (StrEnglishName) and the same "IntTypeID" in which all bird species are numbered 1, butterflies 2, dragonflies 3 etc.

My idea is to have a dropdown list so that I can display all bird species or butterflies etc. based on the selection made. The dropdown list will be based on "type" table and then the results will be based on the "species" table - i.e. if you select birds, all birds from the "species" table will be displayed.

Sorry for the somewhat convoluted description above but I hope someone can help explain how I go about this task.

Thanks in advance for any help
Mike

Comment: plz show wat exact output u want?

Comment: You can google for "javascript/php combobox examples". Something like: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php

Answer (score 0):

you can check which one of select options has checked with php.

First, your html:

```
<form action="yourphpscript.php" method="post">
<select name="select">
<option value="birds">Birds</option>
<option value="butterflies">Butterflies</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And then the php(yourphpscript.php):

```
<?php 
$select = $_POST['select'];

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if ($select = 'birds') {
$id = 1;
}

if ($select = 'butterflies') {
$id = 2;
}

$query = "SELECT /* columns you want to choose */ FROM type, species WHERE type.IntTypeID= species.IntTypeID AND type.IntTypeID = $id AND species.IntTypeID = $id";
} else {echo 'Please select an option!';}
?>
```

hope this will work :)